# Pandas: Comparing all rows within group and check if condition is fulfilled

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compare all rows within a group to check if a condition is fulfilled. If the condition is not fulfilled, I set the new column to True, else False. The issue I am having is finding a neat way to compare all rows within each group. I have something that works but will not work where there are a lot of rows in a group.

```
for i in range(8):
    n = -i-1
    cond=(((df['age']-df['age'].shift(n))*(df['weight']-df['weight'].shift(n)))<0)&(df['ref']==df['ref'].shift(n))&(df['age']<7)&(df['age'].shift(n)<7)
    df['x'+i] = cond.groupby(df['ref']).transform('any')
df.loc[:,'WFA'] = 0
df.loc[(df['x0']==False)&(df['x1']==False)&(df['x2']==False)&(df['x3']==False)&(df['x4']==False)&(df['x5']==False)&(df['x6']==False)&(df['x7']==False),'WFA'] = 1
```

To iterate through each row, I have created a loop that compares adjacent rows (using shift). Each loop represents the next adjacent row. In effect, I am able to compare all rows within a group where the number of rows within a group is 8 or less. As you can imagine, it becomes pretty cumbersome as the number of rows grows large.

Instead of creating of column for each period in shift, I want to see if any row matches the condition with any other row. Then set the new column 'WFA' True or False.

Comment: formatting is pretty bad. hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I post the answer to my own question here (although it is very slow):

```
df.loc[:,'WFA'] = 0
for ref, gref in df.groupby('ref'):
    count=0
    for r_idx, row in gref.iterrows():
        cond = ((((row['age']-gref.loc[gref['age']<7, 'age'])*(row['weight']-gref.loc[gref['age']<7, 'weight']))<0).any())&(row['age']<7)
        if cond==False:
            count+=1
    if count==len(gref):
        df.loc[df['ref']==ref, 'WFA'] = 1
```